# Tool for QA Test Environment (VMs) Management?

Tags: configuration-management, quality-assurance

I want to automate Test machine maintenance work like - software installation/upgrade, OS update installation etc. Instead of writing custom scripts or manually managing each Test Machine, I would like to streamline & automate the process, and centrally manage it.

This is what I am looking for (requirements could change over time):

1. Support for Desktop - Windows, Mac OS and Linux systems
2. Support for tablet and mobile – Android, iOS (Not required. But nice to have. This may be required in future)
3. Ability to Centrally Manage following on Test Machines:

   - Windows Updates
   - System Settings
   - Update/Install Softwares:

     - Test related – TestComplete, Fiddler etc.
     - Browsers-  Firefox, Chrome
     - .Net framework
   - File System – Adding/removing/updating folders, files.
   - Services – Stop, run, restart, install, uninstall
   - Snapshot management for VMs (Managed by Hyper-V)
4. Also a must have feature is the ability to maintain history of the changes done on each test machine.
5. If possible, ability to rollback changes if required.

So let’s say I want to upgrade TestComplete across all my test machines, I should be able to define steps that can be run from a single point on all machines – switch to snapshot -> install new TestComplete version/force update -> update firewall to allow Testcomplete -> reboot machines -> update snapshot.

I am looking for a tool that’s easy to use, scalable, and preferably has a low learning curve .

I would really appreciate any guidance in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [Vagrant Up](https://www.vagrantup.com/), Packer, etc., from [HashiCorp](https://www.hashicorp.com/) the have both Open Source [tools](https://www.hashicorp.com/#open-source-tools) and commercial offerings to allow you to specify & manage the images that your VMs are based on, the software that gets installed and the set-up of the images based on simple, version controllable, text files.